# Having trouble with Equal Method

Tags: java, equals

This is my first post in the forum so please forgive me if I don't post all the right information on my first go-around. Also, this is a class assignment so I am not looking for any answers but simply a second set of eyes and suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong. I am trying to use the equal method to compare the salaries of two clerks with respective outputs (equal or not). I followed the example given in class but I'm clearly doing something wrong since one salary is 35k and the other is 30k so my output should be "not equal". I've included both the Clerk class as well as the test class for anybody that might be able to give me some pointers. Thank you in advance.

```
public class Clerk extends Person {


    private int salary;
    private String grade;

    public Clerk(String name, String address, String telephone, String email, int Salary, String grade) {
        super(telephone, address, name, email);
        setSalary (salary);
        setGrade (grade);

    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
        if (!(obj instanceof Clerk)) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean result = false;

        if (this.salary == ((Clerk) obj).getSalary()) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result;
        result = super.toString() + "  Salary:" + salary + "  Pay Grade:" + grade;
        return result;

    }
}


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Clerk james = new Clerk("J Bishop", "St. Cloud, FL", "407-555-0000","jbiz@aol.com", 35000, "G5");   
        Clerk jose = new Clerk("Jose Gonzalez", "Orlando, FL", "407 555 9999","jgonz@vcc.edu", 30000, "G4");


        if (jose.equals(james)) {
            System.out.println("Jose and James are equal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Jose and James are NOT equal");

        }

        System.out.println(jose);
        System.out.println(james);

    }

}
```

Comment: We'll also need the code for `Person` to be able to run this. On a read-through, though, it looks fine, and I'd suspect that you didn't recompile after editing.

Comment: Oh I misread.. ignore my answer

Answer (score 5):

Careful of caps!

```
public Clerk(String name, String address, String telephone, String email, int salary, String grade) {
```

(`Salary` vs `salary`).

btw excellent post, all the information and code we needed. welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Nice catch. That one was subtle.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for Clerk:

your salary parameter looks like:
`int Salary`

but you set the salary using

`setSalary (salary);`

now the salary you use in setSalary is the class variable. That class variable defaults to 0, so every Clerk you make has salary set to 0. Therefore they are all equal.

Make salary lowercase

Comment: I'd like to thank everybody that took the time to read my question and offer suggestions. Just as some of you suggested, the issue was with the caps (Salary vs salary). These are the little details that I need to continue to work on when coding. Thanks again!